# How to get a list of files that are more than a week old in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux. I was wondering if it is possible to get a list of all the files in a directory that are more than a week old.

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: find /path/to/your/directory -not -mtime -7

Comment: You can use grep with ls -ltr

Answer (score 5):

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +7
```

The first argument is the path to the files. This can be a path, a directory, or a wildcard as in the example above. 
The second argument, -mtime, is used to specify the number of days old that the file is. If you enter +7, it will find files older than 7 days.

Comment: Note to self, it's not `7d`!